# I made an age calulator and i need to refresh to reuse

Tags: javascript, button, calculator

I'm new to java script and was messing around with an age calculator. I made one that I find to work well but I noticed if you were to use it, you would have to refresh the page to use it again. How could I make it so that you wouldn't need to refresh and all you had to do was enter in another value?

```
    <table id="tableCenter">
        <tr id="yearBornRow">
            <p>What year were they born?</p>
            <input id="yearBorn">
        </tr>
        <tr id="currentYearRow">
            <p>What is the current year?</p>
            <input id="currentYear">
        </tr>
    </table>

    <br>

    <button onclick="showAge()">Submit</button>

    <p id="printCurrentAge">Submit to find the age!</p>
```

and then the js

```
<script>
        var yearBorn = document.getElementById("yearBorn").value

        var currentYear = document.getElementById("currentYear").value

        var age = currentYear - yearBorn

        var possiblity = age++

        function showAge(){
            document.getElementById("printCurrentAge").innerHTML = "The person is either " +possiblity+ " or " +age;
        }
    </script>
```

Thanks for any help in advanced

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are performing arithmetic with your values, you need to properly parse them as integers so you can use them via the [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) function :

```
var yearBorn = parseInt(document.getElementById("yearBorn").value);
var currentYear =  parseInt(document.getElementById("currentYear").value);
var age = currentYear - yearBorn
var possiblity = age + 1;
```

You'll also want to add this within your `showAge()` function so it is calculated each time the button is clicked :

```
function showAge(){
        var yearBorn = parseInt(document.getElementById("yearBorn").value);
        var currentYear =  parseInt(document.getElementById("currentYear").value);
        var age = currentYear - yearBorn
        var possiblity = age + 1;
        document.getElementById("printCurrentAge").innerHTML = "The person is either " +possiblity+ " or " +age;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to just move your variables inside function. It will work like a charm!!. Do like below :

```
<script>


    function showAge(){
        var yearBorn = document.getElementById("yearBorn").value

        var currentYear = document.getElementById("currentYear").value

        var age = currentYear - yearBorn

        var possiblity = age++

        document.getElementById("printCurrentAge").innerHTML = "The person is either " +possiblity+ " or " +age;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

java program to get the Date of Birth and ﬁnd Your age in years, months and days.

```
import java.time.*;
// import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FindAge {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int year,month,day;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter Your Date Of Birth : \n");
        System.out.print("Enter the year  : ");
        year = sc.nextInt();
        int y = year;
        System.out.print("Enter the month : ");
        month = sc.nextInt();
        int m = month;
        System.out.print("Enter the day   : ");
        day = sc.nextInt();
        int d = day;
        sc.close();
        LocalDate bdate = LocalDate.of(y, m, d);
        LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();
        Period diff = Period.between(bdate, now);
        System.out.printf("\n You are is  %d years, %d months and %d days old.\n\n",
                diff.getYears(), diff.getMonths(), diff.getDays());
    }
}
```